# Is the only way to raise a software interrupt on a x86 CPU through the BIOS?

Tags: windows, interrupt-handling

I was actually under the impression that this was kind of old fashioned, and that modern operating systems (Windows, Linux) were calling the CPU directly.

**EDIT:**
I read it on the [BIOS interrupt call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_interrupt_call) article on wikipedia.

> For example, to print a character to the screen using BIOS interrupt 0x10 [...]

Comment: no. they still use `int` calls. but that has nothing to do with "bios". Modern OSes don't use the bios for anything except initial bootups. bios is a realmode 16bit dinosaur, finally going the way of the rest of the dinosaurs now that full protected-mode UFI is taking over.

Comment: There is no situation, regardless of the operating system, in which it is sensible to say that you "raise a software interrupt through the BIOS".  In DOS and other BIOS-based operating systems it is the other way around: you invoke the BIOS through a software interrupt.  If there is a meaningful question here it is too well hidden for me to deduce; perhaps you could clarify?

Comment: Edited to help clarify what I mean.

Comment: That article says the same thing I did: software interrupts are how you invoke the BIOS.  The sample code following the sentence you quote raises software interrupt 0x10 to invoke the BIOS "print character to screen" function.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Doesn't this imply, that if you want to print a character to the screen using interrupts, you _have_ to use the BIOS, and so interrupts are raised via the BIOS.

Comment: No.  For example, if you're running MS-DOS (or the MS-DOS emulator in 32-bit Windows) you can raise software interrupt 0x21 with AH=6 to invoke MS-DOS to print a character to the screen.  If you're running Windows, you can raise software interrupt 3 to invoke a Windows debugger breakpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a modern application does not and cannot use BIOS interrupts (as they must be called from 16-bit mode).

Software interrupts are used for system calls, which let an application pass control to the operating system to do something (e.g. file access) which the application is not allowed to do (like writing to video memory or accessing the hardware).